# Command line to convert JSON object to URL Query String

Tags: json, url, curl

I'm looking for a CLI that convert a JSON object into URL Query String:

```
{
  "action_name": "Example",
  "idsite": 1,
  "rec": 1,
  "r": 345007,
  "h": 22,
  "m": 58,
  "s": 47,
  "url": "http://example.com",
  "_id": "44ebfeb79a5bb5e6",
  "_idts": 1539806328,
  "_idvc": 1,
  "_idn": 0,
  "_refts": 0,
  "_viewts": 1539806328,
  "send_image": 1,
  "cookie": 1,
  "res": "412x732",
  "gt_ms": 266,
  "pv_id": "bQkkXv"
}
```

The result will be something like it:

```
curl -Gi 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/piwik.php?action_name=Example&idsite=1&rec=1&r=345007&h=22&m=58&s=47&url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F&_id=44ebfeb79a5bb5e6&_idts=1539806328&_idvc=1&_idn=0&_refts=0&_viewts=1539806328&send_image=1&cookie=1&res=412x732&gt_ms=266&pv_id=bQkkXv'
```

Comment: I know that exists the VisitorGenerator plugin for Matomo/Piwik. I'm using this code just for exemplify.

Comment: I'm also looking for something like this.

Comment: note: in your question, you either have an extra `%2F` in the query string (or a missing `/` in the json field `url` ;-) )

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) with the below filter

`[to_entries[] | (@uri "\(.key)" + "=" + @uri "\(.value)")] | join("&")`

```
$ jq -r '[to_entries[] | (@uri "\(.key)" + "=" + @uri "\(.value)")] | join("&")' << JSON
{
    "var1":"value 1",
    "another var":"Some value with special & = [ ] chars"
}
JSON
var1=value%201&another%20var=Some%20value%20with%20special%20%26%20%3D%20%5B%20%5D%20chars
```

see it live at https://jqplay.org/s/lu0TAWF2HHf

## filter empty / null values

prefix the jq filter with `with_entries(select(.value | length !=0)) |`

https://jqplay.org/s/6jQpPs5EepJ

Answer (score 1):

You could use [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel):

```
xidel -se 'request-combine("http://127.0.0.1:8000/piwik.php",{"action_name":"Example",...})/url'
```

It's unclear what OS you're using. If you're on Windows, then swop the quotes:

```
xidel -se "request-combine('http://127.0.0.1:8000/piwik.php',{'action_name':'Example',...})/url"
```